# Why ‘procedure’ is invalid word (i.e. red word) in SquirreL SQL pane?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, squirrel-sql

I am using DB2 net driver for my db.

I can’t even execute

```
DROP PROCEDURE TESTING_PROC;
```

and the error is:

> Error: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC:
>   ESUB_TEST.TESTING_PROC

- I want to know why PROCEDURE is invalid word
- I can’t even process any procedure in my DB.

**P.S:**
 I’m new to stored procedure.

I will be so kind to see any help from you guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704:  An undefined object or constraint name was detected`.

Check whether you have Stored procedure in this name `TESTING_PROC`

[DB2 – SQL Error Code and Description](http://urssanj00.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/db2-sql-error-code-and-description/)